# Apply DropShadow as separate layer on JavaFX canvas

Tags: java, canvas, javafx, paint, layer

I'm making a paint program but where there is a `DropShadow` around the drawings the user makes. When they erase, it also erases the `DropShadow`. If I try to reapply the `DropShadow` (to get it to surround the drawing's new boundaries), it works, but it makes the rest of the already applied `DropShadow` darker which I don't want.

The solutions I can think of are two-fold:

1. Remove `DropShadow` effect and reapply it on every erase. As far as I know this is not possible while using `GraphicsContext.applyEffect()`
2. Apply `DropShadow` on a separate canvas and clear it and redraw on every erase. The code below implements my embarrassing attempt at this solution.

Here is a picture of what happens currently:
[image]

Here is my code

**FXMLDocument.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="399.0" prefWidth="465.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.60" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="cartographerfx.FXMLDocumentController">
    <children>
      <Pane fx:id="canvasPane" layoutX="26.0" layoutY="20.0" prefHeight="362.0" prefWidth="417.0" style="-fx-border-style: solid;">
         <children>
            <Canvas fx:id="canvas" height="362.0" onMouseDragged="#CanvasMouseDragged" onMousePressed="#CanvasMouseDown" onMouseReleased="#CanvasMouseUp" width="417.0" />
         </children>
      </Pane>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**FXMLDocumentController.java**

```
package cartographerfx;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.effect.DropShadow;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseButton;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;

/**
 *
 * @author Dan
 */
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    Canvas canvas;
    Canvas shadowLayer;

    @FXML
    Pane canvasPane;

    private GraphicsContext gc;
    private GraphicsContext sgc;
    private boolean isDragging;
    private double lastX;
    private double lastY;

    @FXML
    public void CanvasMouseDragged(MouseEvent event) {

        if (isDragging) {
            if (event.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY) {

                gc.setStroke(Color.BLUE);

                gc.setLineWidth(10);
                gc.strokeLine(lastX, lastY, event.getX(), event.getY());
            } else if (event.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY) {
                gc.clearRect(event.getX(), event.getY(), 10, 10);
            }

            lastX = event.getX();
            lastY = event.getY();
        }


    }

    @FXML
    public void CanvasMouseDown(MouseEvent event) {
        isDragging = true;

        lastX = event.getX();
        lastY = event.getY();

        if (event.getButton() == MouseButton.MIDDLE)
        {
            sgc = gc;
            sgc.applyEffect(new DropShadow());

        }
    }

    @FXML
    public void CanvasMouseUp(MouseEvent event) {
        isDragging = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

        gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
        isDragging = false;

        shadowLayer = new Canvas(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());

        sgc = shadowLayer.getGraphicsContext2D();
        canvasPane.getChildren().add(shadowLayer);
        shadowLayer.toBack();
    }

}
```

**CartographerFX.java**

```
package cartographerfx;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author Dan
 */
public class CartographerFX extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why everybody seems to be using the Canvas when the scene-graph would be much better suited for the task. Why don't you just use an ordinary Pane and a Path. You can then apply the drop shadow effect directly to the path. The advantage of the scene-graph is that you can edit every element individually as often as you want whereas the canvas basically is conceptually just an image which you cannot edit at all once it is drawn.

Comment: Lol when you google "draw with javafx" every result uses canvas, but I looked into it and using the scene-graph seems like it could do this just fine. Do you know how I could put in an eraser with behaviour similar to `clearRect()`?

Comment: Have a look at this tutorial: http://blog.ngopal.com.np/2011/06/18/shapes-intersection-subtract-and-union-in-javafx-2-0/ For an eraser the Shape subtract method can be used.